# Connecting to HIVE using a .Net application

Tags: c#, .net, hadoop, hive, odbc

I am trying to create a POC for one of my projects which would allow me to connect to HIVE using an ODBC connection string.

I have been successful in using a DSN method to connect to HIVE. But this doesnt work for me cause I would need to allow create connections during run time where the connection source can be changed from one host to another.

I am using the following connection string (using the Microsoft ODBC driver) which I took from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/738141/How-to-Communicate-to-Hadoop-via-Hive-using-NET-Cs

```
var conn = new OdbcConnection {
    ConnectionString = @
    "DRIVER={Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver};
Host=<IP>;
Port=10000;
User Name=root;Password=<PWD>;
Database=default;
HiveServerType=2;
ApplySSPWithQueries=1;
TrustedCerts=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver\lib\cacerts.pem;
AsyncExecPollInterval=100;
AuthMech=0;
CAIssuedCertNamesMismatch=0;"
}

using(conn) {
    conn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText =
        "SELECT * FROM categories;";

    DbDataReader dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    dt.Load(dr);
}
```

When I try to open the connection, I get a network timeout.

```
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][HiveODBC] (34) Error from Hive: ETIMEDOUT.
```

I am not sure how to fix this up.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for it. you are missing user name, pwd  from your connection string change it as follow:

```
     ConnectionString = @"
                        Dsn=Sample Microsoft Hive DSN;
                        applysspwithqueries=1;asyncexecpollinterval=100;
                        authmech=3;binarycolumnlength=32767;
                        caissuedcertnamesmismatch=0;
                        decimalcolumnscale=10;
                        gettableswithquery=0;
                        host=*******;
                        port=10000;
                        rowsfetchedperblock=10000;
                        trustedcerts={C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver\lib\cacerts.pem};
                        Schema=default;
                        uid=************;
                        pwd=************"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it working after going through the information [in this blog post](http://dzapart.blogspot.in/2015/02/using-hortonworks-hive-in-net.html).

This is the connection string I used.

```
var connectionstring = @"DRIVER={Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver};                                        
                        Host=******;
                        Port=10000;
                        Schema=default;
                        HiveServerType=2;
                        ApplySSPWithQueries=1;
                        AsyncExecPollInterval=100;
                        HS2AuthMech=2;
                        UserName=******;
                        trustedcerts={C:\Program Files\Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver\lib\cacerts.pem}";
```